# Two functions having same body different name

Tags: c++, function

Is it possible to have two functions with the different function name but the same functionality share the function body? And how can we do it?

```
template<typename _T>
class array {
public:
    _T operator+(_T concatinate_operand); // concatinate to the array
    _T append(_T concatinate_operand);
};
```

Comment: You can just have one call other.

Comment: But you need different `+` operator overload semantic. I.e. something like `array& operator+(const array& rhs) { append(rhs.data_,rsh.length_); return *this;  };`

Comment: Utterly and totally unrelated: Show a wee bit of fear any time you precede an upper case letter with an underscore. For why, read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is quite easy to accomplish.  You just call the function the you do the actual implementation in from the other one.  That would look like

```
template<typename _T>
class array {
public:
    _T operator+(_T concatinate_operand) { return append(concatinate_operand); } // concatinate to the array
    _T append(_T concatinate_operand) { /*actual logic here*/ }
};
```

---

Do note that if `T` is large then passing it by value and getting a copy will hurt the performance.  If you use references like

```
template<typename _T>
class array {
public:
    _T& operator+(const _T& concatinate_operand) { return append(concatinate_operand); } // concatinate to the array
    _T& append(const _T& concatinate_operand) { /*actual logic here*/ }
};
```

You will avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: It would be odd for `operator+` to return a `T&`. Or maybe the oddity is that `operator+` and `append` are expected to do the same thing.

Comment: `_T& operator+(const _T& concatinate_operand)` is actually bad idea :)  `char * foo = nullptr;  if(some) { array<char> arr("abcd",5);  foo = arr + "12345"; } delete [] foo;`

Comment: @VictorGubin What is that code suppose to be/do? It wouldn't compile and it seems to be trying to do terrible things.

Comment: @VictorGubin That code won't work in the first place.

Comment: @NathanOliver Exactly like member operator `+` returning reference on member pointer. And `foo = arr + "12345"` may work if not `template<> array<char> { explicit array(const char* cstr) {} `

Comment: @VictorGubin I'm sorry but I don't understand the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @NathanOliver Check operator '+' result type, it returns reference on on template parameter type,  when it should return reference on array class type. i.e. something like `array<char> c = array<char>("abcd",5) + array<char>("fig",4);`

Comment: @VictorGubin Why?  That is not what the OP has.  It looks like the want to use `+` or `append` to add an element to the end of the array.